# I want to create this UI

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create this UI.

[image]

I have done this work.

```
   <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="274dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/car"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="PP AUTOMATIVES"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ratingimage"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/offersimage"


        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/heartimage"

       />

     </RelativeLayout>

     </RelativeLayout>
```

I am not able to set alignment of images and set background color, margin and style of TextView according to "OFFICEWork" UI.

Comment: I recommend you use 9-patch images for it and set the stretchable areas.

Comment: use framelayout instead

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/car">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#f7f7f8"
        android:padding="2dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="PP AUTOMATIVES"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ratingimage" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/offersimage" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/heartimage" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How to add the background shadow of "PP Automatives" TextView according the "OfficeWork UI"?